# how could I store the user input information and store to admin page using php

Tags: php

Please kindly see my PHP code as below:

It is 2 files. My questions are how could I store the user input information and store it to admin pages. how could I make the confirmation message to users if they input correctly? how could I create the admin page with fetching data and displaying it? how could I make the password gating for the admin page? Please kindly help with my assignment. Thank you

File name: content.php

```
    <h2>PHP Assignment 1 </h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field </span></p>
<form  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  method="post">
First Name:
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $FirstName;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $FirstNameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Last Name:
<input type="text"name="LastName" value="<?php echo $LastName;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $LastNameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Email Address:
<input type="text" name="EmailAddress" value="<?php echo $EmailAddress;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $EmailAddressErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
</form>
```

File name: process.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>.error {color: #FF0000;} </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
$FirstNameErr = $LastNameErr = $EmailAdressErr ="";
$FirstName = $LastName = $EmailAddress = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["FirstName"])) {
        $FirstNameErr = "First Name is required";
    } else {
        $FirstName = test_input($_POST["FirstName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $FirstName)){
            $FirstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
        else echo $FirstName;
    }

if (empty($_POST["LastName"])) {
    $LastNameErr = "Last Name is required";
} else {
    $LastName = test_input($_POST["LastName"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $LastName)){
        $LastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["EmailAddress"])){
    $EmailAddressErr = "Email Address is required";    
} else {
    $EmailAddress = test_input($_POST["EmailAddress"]);
    if (!filter_var($EmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $EmailAddressErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
}
}

function test_input($data){
    $data= trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>

enter code here

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>.error {color: #FF0000;} </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
$FirstNameErr = $LastNameErr = $EmailAdressErr ="";
$FirstName = $LastName = $EmailAddress = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["FirstName"])) {
        $FirstNameErr = "First Name is required";
    } else {
        $FirstName = test_input($_POST["FirstName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $FirstName)){
            $FirstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
        else echo $FirstName;
    }

if (empty($_POST["LastName"])) {
    $LastNameErr = "Last Name is required";
} else {
    $LastName = test_input($_POST["LastName"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/", $LastName)){
        $LastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["EmailAddress"])){
    $EmailAddressErr = "Email Address is required";    
} else {
    $EmailAddress = test_input($_POST["EmailAddress"]);
    if (!filter_var($EmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $EmailAddressErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
}
}

function test_input($data){
    $data= trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid your question is far too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the right way to do it in the real world, but it does give you a very good starting point include the fundementals which you can work from. It mostly covers all requirements, however, there are some key areas that need improving: admin authentication and error handling for database errors etc.

Here's a video of it the below in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmaEYzIkpnY

There are 4 files that powers this example:

1. `database.php` which includes the database connection helper. **Databse connection details will need updating to match your enviroment.**
2. `forms.php` is a file containing variables and helper functions for form validation.
3. `index.php` which is your "frontend" form for users details.
4. `admin.php` which is where you'd login to view all recorded submissions.

In summary:

- Errors are simply stored in an array and then presented with the helper functions `has_error()` and `get_error()`.
- Data storage is handled with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) research this along with prepared statements.
- Gated admin area is hardcoded variable value checking and should not be used. You should instead have a users table which stores the password as a hashed value, your authentication process would then check against these values and set session values.
- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is used for the basic UI.

**database.php**

```php
<?php

/**
 * Open a new database connection.
 *
 * @return PDO
 */
function db_connect() {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'mysql';
    $name = 'my_table';

    try {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name;charset=UTF8", $user, $pass);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Database connectuon failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**forms.php**

```php
<?php

/**
 * @var array $payload
 */
$payload = [];

/**
 * @var string[] $error_bag
 */
$error_bag = [];

/**
 * @var bool $success
 */
$success = false;

/**
 * Set the global payload array.
 *
 * @param array $data
 */
function set_payload(array $data) {
    global $payload;
    $payload = $data;
}

/**
 * Add an error to the global error bag.
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $error
 */
function add_error(string $name, string $error) {
    global $error_bag;
    $error_bag[$name] = $error;
}

/**
 * Check if input has errors.
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return bool
 */
function has_error(string $name) {
    global $error_bag;
    return array_key_exists($name, $error_bag);
}

/**
 * Get the error for input.
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return null|string
 */
function get_error(string $name) {
    global $error_bag;
    return has_error($name) ? $error_bag[$name] : null;
}

/**
 * Get input from request.
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed|null
 */
function input(string $name, $default = null) {
    global $payload;
    return array_key_exists($name, $payload) ? $_POST[$name] : $default;
}
```

**index.php**

```php
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
require_once 'forms.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    set_payload($_POST);

    $first_name = input('first_name');
    $last_name = input('last_name');
    $email_address = input('email_address');

    if (empty(trim($first_name))) {
        add_error('first_name', 'Please provide a first name.');
    }

    if (empty(trim($last_name))) {
        add_error('last_name', 'Please provide a last name.');
    }

    if (empty(trim($email_address)) || !filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        add_error('email_address', 'Please provide a valid email address.');
    }

    // If empty, assume all fields are valid.
    if (empty($error_bag)) {

        // Empty payload on success, prevents form values from being filled.
        set_payload([]);

        $database = db_connect();

        $database->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS submissions (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` longtext NOT NULL,
  `last_name` longtext NOT NULL,
  `email_address` longtext NOT NULL,
  primary key (`id`)
) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");

        $query = $database->prepare('INSERT INTO `submissions` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address`) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email_address)');

        $query->execute([
            ':first_name' => $first_name,
            ':last_name' => $last_name,
            ':email_address' => $email_address
        ]);

        if ($database->lastInsertId()) {
            // Set success flag.
            $success = true;
        } else {
            add_error('database', 'Failed to process submission, please try again later.');
        }
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Submission</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container my-5">

        <h1>PHP Assignment 1 </h1>

        <?php if ($success): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your submission has been recieved.
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if (has_error('database')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Uh oh!</strong> <?= htmlspecialchars(get_error('database')); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <form action="index.php"  method="post">

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="first-name">First name:</label>
                <input
                        type="text"
                        id="first-name"
                        name="first_name"
                        class="form-control <?= has_error('first_name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                        value="<?= htmlspecialchars(input('first_name')); ?>">
                <?php if (has_error('first_name')): ?>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?= get_error('first_name'); ?></div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="last-name">Last name:</label>
                <input
                        type="text"
                        id="last-name"
                        name="last_name"
                        class="form-control <?= has_error('last_name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                        value="<?= htmlspecialchars(input('last_name')); ?>">
                <?php if (has_error('last_name')): ?>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?= get_error('last_name'); ?></div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email-address">Email address:</label>
                <input
                        type="email"
                        id="email-address"
                        name="email_address"
                        class="form-control <?= has_error('email_address') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                        value="<?= htmlspecialchars(input('email_address')); ?>">
                <?php if (has_error('email_address')): ?>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?= get_error('email_address'); ?></div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**admin.php**

```php
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
require_once 'forms.php';

/**
 * @var bool $authed
 */
$authed = false;

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    set_payload($_POST);

    $username = input('username');
    $password = input('password');

    if (empty(trim($username))) {
        add_error('username', 'Please enter your username.');
    }

    if (empty(trim($password))) {
        add_error('password', 'Please enter your password.');
    }

    if (empty($error_bag) && ($username !== 'test' || $password !== 'password1')) {
        add_error('username', 'The details provided were incorrect.');
    }

    // If empty, assume all fields are valid.
    if (empty($error_bag)) {

        // Empty payload on success, prevents form values from being filled.
        set_payload([]);

        // Set success flag.
        $authed = true;
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Admin area</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="bg-light">

<div class="container my-5">

    <?php if ($authed): ?>
        <h1>Submission results</h1>
        <?php

        $database = db_connect();

        $results = $database->query('SELECT * FROM `submissions`')->fetchAll();

        ?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bg-white">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Email address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php if ($results): ?>
                    <?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($result['id']); ?></td>
                            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($result['first_name']); ?></td>
                            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($result['last_name']); ?></td>
                            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($result['email_address']); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php else:?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">No results</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form  action="admin.php"  method="post">

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="first-name">Username:</label>
                                <input
                                        type="text"
                                        id="username"
                                        name="username"
                                        class="form-control <?= has_error('username') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                                        value="<?= htmlspecialchars(input('username')); ?>">
                                <?php if (has_error('username')): ?>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?= get_error('username'); ?></div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="last-name">Password:</label>
                                <input
                                        type="password"
                                        id="password"
                                        name="password"
                                        class="form-control <?= has_error('password') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                                        value="<?= htmlspecialchars(input('password')); ?>">
                                <?php if (has_error('password')): ?>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?= get_error('password'); ?></div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Levi, Thank you very much for your code. Very useful for my understanding of PHP. I am studying now. Deeply appreciated your help !!!!!